# Ruby Server with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, windows-7

So, I'm writing a basic application, with a html5/jquery front end and a ruby backend. I've never used a ruby backend, and was wondering how I'd go about that. I am going to be using MySQL, very much like an Apache/MySQL/PHP thing but without PHP. I will need to eventually put the application on some sort of web server. For now I just need something local so I can develop it. So, is there a WAMP for ruby instead of php? I've been reading and Ruby on Rails seems like it may be what I'm looking for, but I'm really not sure.

So, what kind of platform do I need to learn in order to do this. I want to use ajax if possible(ruby backend). How do I go about setting up my environment.

Sorry if my question is somewhat vague, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: What platform are you using for development? There's some quick-start apps, but they're different for Mac vs. Windows

Comment: I'm developing on Windows 7 64-bit, but I could do it on ubuntu if I have to. I'd just rather not because I don't have it running at the moment.

Thank!

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I don't post here very often and I really don't know the way things work around here. I'll go do that now.

Comment: I got it up to 100%, what would be my best course of action to get some attention on my question? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO [railsinstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) is the way to get started on Windows.

For getting started with Rails itself, [Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) is great.

Comment: So is rails necessary? Or could I just do this with straight ruby?

Thanks!

Comment: @Scriptonaut *Strictly* necessary? Nope, you could do something CGI-ish, but yuck. You could certainly use a different framework (e.g., Sinatra), but honestly on Windows, I'd let somebody else do the grunt work of figuring out how to make everything work, hence *railsinstaller*. Otherwise I'd fire up that Linux box.

Comment: Ok, so rails is definitely preferable then? If so, I will do it in rails, I have nothing against it. It's something I've been wanting to learn anyways. Thanks :)

Comment: @Scriptonaut It's not so much that Rails is preferable, but that doing anything on Windows generally sucks--unless there's a pre-packaged solution, I wouldn't bother--but that's just me. I'd run a VM first.

Answer (score 1):

When I was developing in Rails on Windows I used rails installer as Dave Newton said.  For local development you can either use the bundled database SQLite and the bundled WEBrick server which means you don't need to install Apache or MYSQL.  If you really want to though, [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) worked for me to provide MYSQL and Apache services on Windows.